# Using DATEADD and DATEDIFF truncates the time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, datetime, dateadd

I am using the following to get to get the 1st day of next month with time:

```
select DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, -1, getdate()), 0)
```

But the output is:

```
 2018-12-01 00:00:00.000
```

And the expected result is:

```
 2018-12-01 11:53:30.677
```

I have tried various approaches but not able to get required output. I am using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

You can add two `datetime` values, one for the date and the other for the time:

```
select DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, -1, getdate()), 0) + cast(cast(getdate() as time) as datetime)
```

I am guessing that you want the time value from the current time.

Answer (score 1):

Subtract `DAY(@date) - 1` days from `@date` to get first day of that month including time. Then add one month:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, 1, DATEADD(DAY, -DAY(GETDATE()) + 1, GETDATE()))
-- 2018-12-01 04:52:33.403
```

Comment: `-DAY(GETDATE()) + 1` could be simplified to `1-DAY(GETDATE())`. Other then that, +1.

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
select DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, -1, getdate()), 0)+  convert(DATETIME,'11:53:30.677')
```

in case of current time it would be like below

```
select DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, -1, getdate()), 0)+  convert(datetime, convert(time,getdate()))
```